# Fetch the recyclerview data based on the data id

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, row

I have one recycler view. when I am clicking on the recycler item i am going to other activity and i am doing some task there and finishing that activity. And when I am clicking on the recycler item I am saving that data id in a variable, not position. So, when i am coming back from second activity to first activity i want to update the data of the particular recycler row item which one i clicked. I have the Id of that particular, I cant do with the positions. 
Any one please help me out of this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: loop through all items, and find the one with your ID, and update it.

Comment: In activity or adapter?

Comment: that depends on how you store your variables.

Comment: yes i did that onResume... working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps.

1. implement onClick in YourFirstActivity
2. in onClick your are getting the position right. now get the data from your List
   as YourClass var = list.get(position);
3. from var your can get id and all other data.
4. start SecondActivity.class as startActivityForResults
5. onActivityResult in your FirstActivity.class now you can do what ever you want to do